# Battery of 2018 MacBook Pro won't charge

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power

Specifically, the battery won't charge when connected via power adapter. If I go to the battery menu in the menu bar, I no longer see an option "Charge to full now" like I used to before. I have tried restarting the computer, resetting the SMC (though I may have done it incorrectly), changing ports, and even changing outlets. I have not tried another adapter (though when I connected my iPad to the adapter, it started charging).

[image: Battery menu]

Comment: After five years, a battery may very well be too old. If you open Battery Settings, what do you see?

Comment: While the linked dupe references a 2012, the issue is still exactly the same.  Battery technology may have gotten *better*, but it hasn't really evolved; it's still a chemical reaction that moves ions through a permeable membrane.  Your battery has a cell or cells that have died and will no longer charge.

Comment: Take it to an Apple Store for assessment.